# Imputing panel data in the wide format, obtaining pooled standard errors after using lmer

Tags: lme4-nlme, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, multiple-imputation, mice

I have a longitudinal data set with missing values. I want to multiply impute (let us say $m$ = 20 times) the missing values in the wide format using the R-package *mice*. Thereafter, I would like to fit a multilevel model based on the imputed data with the function *lmer* from the R-package *lme4*. The function *lmer* does, however, only seem to be able to fit a model based on the long format.

I therefore extracted the 20 imputed datasets with the function *complete* from *mice* and converted each data frame into the long format using the function *pivot_longer* from the *tidyr* package. Subsequently, I fitted a multilevel model on each long-format dataset using *lmer*, resulting in 20 regression outputs. This works.

However, I would eventually want to obtain standard errors of the estimated regression parameters that are based on the within-imputation and between-imputation variance (the whole reason one does want to use multiple imputation). This is usually easily done with the *mice* function *pool*. However, *pool* can only be used on an object of the class *mira*, which is only obtained if the regression models are **directly** fitted on a object of the *mids* class, which again is the object class that is returned by the function *mice*. Since I converted the multiply imputed data sets, this does not seem to be possible.
I found some similar questions on stack overflow, such as these here:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872668/multiple-imputation-of-longitudinal-data-in-mice-and-statistical-analyses-of-objv)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950304/random-effects-in-longitudinal-multilevel-imputation-models-using-mice?rq=1)

However, all the questions/answers either do not tell how to obtained pooled standard errors or they deal with imputing the data with a multilevel model (such as *mice.impute.2l*), which does not work in my case (imputation fails). I simply want to use a single-level model, as outlined here: https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-fdd.html

Can anybody give adivce?

Comment: I'm very happy to have found this question because it was exactly one I was going to ask. Even happier that there is this solution.
I just wanted to check though. At what stage do you convert the list to long format?
Regarding Erik's code, my DV is imputed in wide format e.g df <- mice(df1, method = meth, predictorMatrix = predM, m=20, maxit = 20) Where df1 contains
ID
DV_Group1
DV_Group2
DV_Group3
DV_Group4 DV_Group6
IV1
IV2
IV3
IV4 At what point do I convert the df to long format?

Comment: Hi!

I extracted the multiply imputed datasets, which I had imputed in the wide format, with the function "complete". Directly after that, I converted the data frame into the long format using the function "pivot_longer". Subsequently, I stacked the 20 long-format data sets (and the original data with missing values) into one big data frame including the column "imp", which indicates the number of the imputed data set (number 0 for the original data frame with missing values). Then I used the "as.mitml.list" function as written by Erik Ruzek.

I hope I was able to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the imputed datasets are in long form (dataset 2 stacked onto dataset 1) then you can use [mitml](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mitml/index.html) the to do the pooling of the estimates from your model to give you the correct standard errors. See the code below:

```
library(mitml) 

### Define a list that mitml will link to the multiply imputed data.

implist <-  as.mitml.list(split(df, df$imp)) #imp is the variable that identifies the imputed dataset an observation belongs to
    
### Analyze the imputed datasets and pool the results. 

m_imp <- "DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3 + (1 || Group)"
analysis <- with(implist, lmer(m_imp, REML = F))
estimates <- testEstimates(analysis, var.comp = T, df.com = NULL)
estimates
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!